# error when login with twitter swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, authentication, twitter-login

i want to login with twitter but i get this error

> Request failed: forbidden (403)

this error happen when i login with twitter only when i don't have twitter app on my phone but if have the twitter app on my phone it login normally.

so why i get this error.

i use this code for twitter.

```
@IBAction func twtBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if !Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
        Helper.instance.showAlert(self, title: "no conection ", message: "Please check your internet connection", buttonTitle: "Ok", buttonAction: nil)
    }else{
        Helper.instance.startIndicator2(self, "show", self.lang!, hudd)
        print("twitter btn Pressed")
        LoginVC.type = "T"

        Helper.instance.fetchDataFromTwt(completion: { (id, name, email, image) in
            if (id != nil && name != nil && email != nil) {
                print("Log in successfully")
                print("Login successfully")
                print(id!,name!,email!)
                APIHelper.apiCore.login_Social(email!, name!, self.self.lang!, "\(id!)","twitter", completion: { (code, message) in
                    if code == 200 {
                        print("Api_token: \((message)!)")
                        Helper.instance.saveApiToken(token: message!)
                        Helper.instance.startIndicator2(self, "showw", self.self.lang!, hudd)
                        ProfileVC.twtImage = image
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ProfileVC", sender: nil)

                    }else{
                        print("Error: \(String(describing: message))")
                        Helper.instance.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: message!, buttonTitle: "Ok", buttonAction: { (action) in
                            Helper.instance.startIndicator2(self, "showw", self.self.lang!, hudd)
                        })

                    }
                })
            }
        })

    }

}
```

and to fetch data from twitter app i use this code.

```
func fetchDataFromTwt(completion: @escaping (_ id:Int?,_ name:String?,_ email: String?,_ image: String?)-> Void){

    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn { (session, error) in

        if (session != nil) {

            print("signed in as \(session!.userName)");
            let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()

            let request = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "GET", urlString: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json", parameters: ["include_entities": "false", "include_email": "true", "skip_status": "true"], error: nil)

            client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { response, data, connectionError in

                if connectionError != nil {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: connectionError))")

                }else{
                    do {
                        let twitterJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]

                        let name = twitterJson["name"]
                        let id = twitterJson["id"]
                        let email = twitterJson["email"]
                        let image = twitterJson["profile_image_url_https"]

                        print(name!,id!,email!,image!)

                        completion(id as? Int, name as? String, email as? String, image as? String)

                    } catch let jsonError as NSError {
                        print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")

                    }
                }

            }

        } else {
            print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In SSO must require app installed in your device. If you want user can login without app install then follow these steps: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 1):

Please check what is the callback url assigned in the twitter developer portal on settings Menu for your application . it has to be in the format `twitterkit-apiKey://`.  If you have an apiKey like abc you should add `twitterkit-abc://`.